# Weird Remesher result

Tags: mesh, sculpting, remesh

I'm in Sculpting mode and trying to remesh a simple geometry but getting weird result. The only way I found to solve this is solidifying the mesh but I wonder if is it possible to remesh flat planes in Blender as we do in zBrush. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mesh must be manifold in order to produce a proper remesh result.

The easiest way to do this would be extruding the faces downwards by a very small amount, or as you did before by solidifying your mesh. From my own experiences the blender remesher is not able to remesh non-manifold meshes.